# Linear algebra endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
f(A) = A \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
       - \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} A
$$

How do you calculate the characteristic polynomial, the  minimum polynomial and when it's diagonalizable and the invariant subspaces in the reals and complex? Thanks

Comment: It seems that $f$ is an endomorphism of the space of $2 \times 2$ matrices. Well, this is a $4$-dimensional space, and it has a canonical basis. Write down the $4 \times 4$ matrix of $f$, and proceed as usual.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{B} = \{B_1, B_2, B_3,B_4 \}$ is a basis for $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{F})$ (where $\mathbb{F}$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).

Where $B_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, B_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, B_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, B_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}_.$

\begin{align*}
f(B_1) &= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\\
&= B_2 - B_3 \\
\\
f(B_2) &= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1-\alpha \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\\
&= B_1 + (1-\alpha)B_2 - B_4\\
\\
f(B_3) &= \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
\alpha - 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\\
&= -B_1 + (\alpha-1)B_3 + B_4 \\
\\
f(B_4) &= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\\
&= -B_2 + B_3
\end{align*}

So the matrix of $f$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ is $$F = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
1 & 1-\alpha & 0 & -1\\
-1 & 0 & \alpha -1 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}_.$$

Since $F$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable. Its characteristic polynomial is $x^2(x^2 - (\alpha^2-2\alpha + 5)) = x^2(x-\sqrt{\alpha^2-2\alpha + 5})(x+ \sqrt{\alpha^2-2\alpha + 5})$. So the eigenvalues are $0,\pm \sqrt{\alpha^2-2\alpha+5}$.

The minimal polynomial should be easy to compute from here. The invariant subspaces are the eigenspaces.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The matrix 
$$
\pmatrix{\alpha & 1\\1&1 }
$$
will have linearly independent eigenvectors $u$ and $v$.  $f$ will have the eigen"vectors" $uu^T,uv^T,vu^T,vv^T$.